# How to make my bot can hold 2 argument commands DiscordJS

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

So I want to make my bot respond to 2 arguments command. My command is `help_unmute` I want to use it without the underscore and leave only `help unmute`.

I just wanted to type `prefix+ help unmute` and then the bot responds.

Here's my code:

```js
if (command === 'help_tempmute' ) {
    message.channel.send({embed: {
        title: '**Tempmute**',
        color: 3066993,
        author: {
            name: 'Legendary Bot',
            icon_url: 'https://i.imgur.com/kUi20Yz.png'
        },
        fields: [
            {
            name: `Description:`,
            value: `Mute a member with a spesific time, also cant be unmuted until the time expired`,
            inline: true
            },
            {
            name: `Usage:`,
            value: `lbtempmute [person][time][reason]`,
            inline: true
            },
            {
            name: `Example:`,
            value: `lbtempmute @Devil Joe 1h harassing member`,
            inline: false
            },
        ],
    }})
}
```

Comment: command.replace('_','') It should replace all _ with an empty space. Or .substring can work too.

Comment: uhh I want my command holds 2 argument, like (prefix)help tempmute

Comment: What does prefix add to it?

Comment: command === 'prefix help tempmute' ?

Comment: the prefix is "&" i made the 
```
const prefix = 'lb'

client.on('message', (message) => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
```
ontop of the command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this in your `on 'message'` event:

```
let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
let cmd = messageArray[0];
let args = messageArray.slice(1);
```

Then `help` is defined as `cmd` and you can get the second argument defined as args[0]. When you now type f. e. `!help unmute` is `!help` defined as `cmd` and `unmute` defined as `args[0]`.

Comment: thanks! that's really helpful, but how do I make an ```if ()``` from it?

Comment: you can do something like: `if(args[0] === 'unmute') {
//your code here
}`

Comment: Can you make the full code? hehe I'm still pretty confused

Comment: https://hastebin.com/wiruxosaca.js - this is the full code